# Self host WCF ServiceHost object lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicehost, self-hosting

To kick off my WCF service, I use the following:

```
selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceClass));
selfHost.Open();
```

At some point this will create an instance of `MyServiceClass`. Will it create a single instance or an instance per request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to restrict it to a single instance you can instantiate your service class outside and the pass the instance into the servicehost:

```
var myservice = new MyServiceClass();
selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceClass), myservice); // forces singleton pattern
selfHost.Open();
```

Comment: Note implementing this will require a change to `MyServiceClass`  to add `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`.  InstanceContextMode is mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore Also if InstanceContextMode.Single is set than there is no really need to create the service host as described in the answer, you can just as well use the constructor of ServiceHost that uses only the created type

Answer (score 4):

By default it's an instance per request but you could change this. For example you could write your own [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) and manage the life of the service class yourself.

Comment: @spender, yes, it can. You could write a custom `IInstanceProvider`. For example this is commonly used with DI frameworks when you want to inject some dependencies into the service class.

Answer (score 4):

All these answers are correct, but they seem more complex than what you are asking. The basics of whether it creates an instance per call, per session, or singleton are controlled by the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) which is an attribute on your service class. Start reading there.

Answer (score 0):

It will create instance per request. If you want a single instance you could use a static class. Static class exists for the lifetime of the application. They don't get reinstantiated every time there is a call or new WCF connection is made.

Comment: Static service class is a bad idea. How is your static class going to implement the ServiceContract interface?

Comment: Thats true, maybe i should be more specific, static class advantage might be used for server side only.